# Enable identity insert ignored using SQL Server Import?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to move a database from a remote server at a web hosting company (meaning I have no control of the server) to my new own server running `SQL Server Express 2012`. To do this, I am using `SQL Server` `Import/Export Wizard`. However, the identity columns om my source database isn't set as identity columns on the destination database. I have tried to enable the `Enable identity insert` tick in the wizard, but the columns are still not created as identity columns in the destination.

How should I do this to get the same database with the same schema on my destination server?
The source database server is `SQL Server 2008`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason why you are not using detaching/attaching the databases or better yet do a full backup and a restore?

Comment: I'm not able to detach the, since I don't have control over the source server. However I was able to do a full backup and restore it on the destination server, so thank you!